# Count rows and columns in Html Table having subtables using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, html-table, html-agility-pack

I'm parsing an Html table and I need the columns and rows count.

I tryed using:

```
ColNum = mTables(1).SelectNodes(".//th").Count
RowNum = mTables(1).SelectNodes(".//tr").Count
```

But I get a wrong results if table has one or more subtables.

Here's a sample of html table I need to parse:

```
<table border='1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>Some Text</th><th>Some Text</th><th>Some Text</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Some data</td><td>Some data
                     <table border='1'>
                         <tbody>
                             <tr><th>Some Text</th><th>Some Text</th></tr>
                             <tr><td>Some Data</td><td>Some Data</td></tr>
                         </tbody>
                     </table><td>Some data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this sample I need this results:
Columns = 3
Rows = 5

How can I get the number of the rows and columns (only for the main table) without counting the subtable rows and columns?

Comment: What is the wrong result you get ? What is the result expected (2 ?) ?

Comment: @Veverke I need to count only main table. Result is (Main Table Columns)+(SubTable Columns) and (Main Table Rows)+(SubTable Rows). I'll edit the question

Comment: So you want to count the th's in the outer table only ?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting correct results, using ScrapySharp nuget package to enable Css Selectors. (I often work with ScrapySharp when working with HtmlAgilityPack).

Add `using ScrapySharp.Extensions;` at the top of your .vb document in the editor.

```
            HtmlDocument d = new HtmlDocument();
            string s = @"
<table border='1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Some Text</th>
            <th>Some Text</th>
            <th>Some Text</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td></tr>
        <td>Some data</td><td>Some data
                     <table border='1'>
                         <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <th>Some Text</th>
                                <th>Some Text</th>
                             </tr>
                             <tr><td>Some Data</td><td>Some Data</td></tr>
                         </tbody>
                     </table><td>Some data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td><td>Some data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>";
            d.LoadHtml(s);

            var node = d.DocumentNode;
            var outerTable = node.CssSelect("tbody tr").FirstOrDefault();

            if (outerTable != null)
            {
                var ths = outerTable.SelectNodes("th");
                Console.WriteLine(ths.Count());
            }
        }
```

Since you want the ths for the 1st table only, the css selector I am using is `tbody tr`, which will return 3 matches, but we want the 1st tr only. (I could use css pseudo selector `:first` here to achieve this in a one line statement but ScrapySharp does not support pseudo selectors).

Outputs 3

Comment: I'm using vb.net . When you say "Add `using ScrapySharp.Extensions`" you mean `imports ScrapySharp.Extensions`? And how I need to declare `ths` in vb.net?

Comment: First of all, I updated my solution - now it returns 3.  Regarding ScrapySharp, it's a nuget package, you install it running `Install-Package ScrapySharp` at the PackageManagerConsole window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for helping: you gave me the spark for the solution ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

I solved this way:

**For columns**:

```
ColNum = mTables(1).SelectSingleNode(".//tbody//tr[1]").SelectNodes(".//th").Count
```

**For Rows**:

**First**: Check for SubTables

```
Dim SubTbl%
Try
    SubTbl% = mTables(1).SelectNodes(".//table").Count
Catch ex As Exception
    SubTbl% = 0
End Try
```

**Then**: Count Rows in Subtables and subtract from total rows

```
Dim SubTRows% = 0
If SubTables > 0 Then
    For SubT As Short = 1 To SubTables
        Dim STRows% = mTables(1).SelectNodes(".//table[" & SubT & "]//tr").Count
        SubTRows += STRows
    Next
    RowsNum = mTables(1).SelectNodes(".//tr").Count - SubTRows
Else
    RowsNum = mTables(1).SelectNodes(".//tr").Count
End If
```

Comment: Why deal with subtracting the irrelevant ones if you know beforehand that you only want the first tr of the first table :) ? That's what my solution is based on.

Comment: @Veverke I don't know how it's possible to count only rows of the main table. In all tests I get all rows so I thought to subtract the subtable's rows. You gave me helpful hint for Columns Count

Comment: I do not know how to do it either, using xpath selection. That's the reason why I suggested adding ScrapySharp to your project, so you can use Css Selectors - and select for "table tr" and get the 1st element only. Seems you did not succeed in installing/using ScrapySharp.

Comment: @Veverke I did it for columns but not for rows. And I had much problems installing HAP so I'm afraid to install and use another package (I'm not a pro)